# Daedalus not showing my wallet, prompting me to restore or create new. No pass phrase

Tags: wallet

Daedalus was not fulling syncing and opening up. In an attempt to sync and get it open I deleted everything in the immutable, ledger, and volatile files. I read that helped fix the problem. I then restarted my computer and when I opened Daedalus it’s now asking to restore the wallet. When I migrated from Byron to Shelley I don’t remember ever being prompted with a new passphrase so I do not have the 24 word phrase and now I’m terrified all my ADA is lost.

I’ve tried importing through the state directory but it’s not finding my wallet and I don’t remember the exact wallet name.

The blocks are currently 52% synced. Im praying for a miracle and that when it fully syncs my wallet will be there.

Please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Your "wallet" is not on your computer, its on the blockchain. The only thing that is stored on your computer is your private keys which allows you to access your functions on the blockchain.

If you are only 52% synced. you should wait.

> I do not have the 24 word phrase

The seed phrase is probably the same as when you created the Byron wallet.

The seed phrase is the only thing you need to restore your wallet.